# Magento2 Checkout page Not Working After Installing New theme

Tags: magento2, checkout

Highly appreciate any help 
I have installed Porto thee to my existing magento store that was built in Luma Theme

I successfully installed Porto Theme and it's modules but my checkout page not working after installing theme even when i click on add to cart button of any product it shows product added in cart . also cart page work fine. but when i click checkout button it go to blank page. Please advice thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Have you find any errors in browser console log on checkout page? if you observe any error please include in your post so that it will very easy to understand the what is the exact issue ? as well please check logs exception and system and debug logs etc..

Comment: mean time my suggestion is raise ticket to porto theme and try to debug from your end as well.

Comment: this is error i getting in console https://snag.gy/JhAGiV.jpg

Comment: cart Page this error console  https://snag.gy/pe2I3r.jpg